# Acyclic Visitor C++

Tags: c++, design-patterns, visitor-pattern

I'm reading the book by Alexandrescu, and I've run into the Acyclic Visitor pattern. I think that it's possible to get rid of the macross that calls AcceptImpl method of the BaseVisitable class.
Could you tell me, whether the following implementation bellow conforms the standard?

```
class BaseVisitor
{
public:
    virtual ~BaseVisitor() {}
};

template <class SpecificVisitable>
class SpecificVisitor
{
public:
    virtual void Visit(SpecificVisitable& t) = 0;

protected:
    ~SpecificVisitor() {}
};

template <class SpecificVisitable>
class BaseVisitable
{
public:
    void Accept(BaseVisitor& visitor)
    {
        SpecificVisitor<SpecificVisitable>& specificVisitor = dynamic_cast<SpecificVisitor<SpecificVisitable>&>(visitor);
        specificVisitor.Visit(static_cast<SpecificVisitable&>(*this));
    }
protected:
    ~BaseVisitable() {}
};

class A : public BaseVisitable<A>
{
public:
    void PrintA() { std::cout << "A\n"; }
};

class B : public BaseVisitable<B>
{
public:
    void PrintB() { std::cout << "B\n"; }
};

class PrintVisitor final:
    public BaseVisitor,
    public SpecificVisitor<A>,
    public SpecificVisitor<B>
{
public:
    virtual void Visit(A& a) override
    {
        a.PrintA();
    }

    virtual void Visit(B& b) override
    {
        b.PrintB();
    }
};

int main()
{
    A a;
    B b;

    PrintVisitor visitor;
    a.Accept(visitor);
    b.Accept(visitor);
}
```

Comment: the dynamic cast to a reference will result in an exception if the visitor does not support the specific type. Is that the desired behaviour?

Comment: Compiles without any errors/warnings with `-std=c++14 -Wall -pedantic` so it conforms the standard. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3d92d105649750a7

Comment: Thanks. I ran it with those options and got no errors or warnings. It looks like it's possible to write this pattern without macros. I wonder why Alexandrescu did not do that.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the commenters to the original post that state that a `dynamic_cast` to a reference will fail. You are not testing that situation, so your code will of course work just fine. But, in the general case, it's wrong.

I recommend that you instead rewrite `BaseVisitable` to instead cast to a pointer and check that pointer before dispatching on it. Something like

```
if (auto sv = dynamic_cast<SpecificVisitor<SpecificVisitable>*>(visitor))
  sv->visit(*this)
```